# Using AWS Cognito to authenticate users in my own api

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I have an iOS app. Users are authenticated to access AWS resources like DynamoDB or S3. Now, I have built a node js server in order to add further logic to the app’s backend. My question is, can I use already authenticated users identity pool to allow those users to access my api (which hosted in EC2, by the way) or I need to create a whole new authentication system using passport.js or such. 
If I can use Cognito, does it cost money?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put your API behind API Gateway, you could use AWS IAM authentication for the API Gateway, an approach I find compelling because it means unauthenticated requests to API gateway don't trigger a backend request, and because I like to let AWS do the authentication for me ( AWS auth is "free" though Cognito identity pools are not) .   I also like that api gateway can do a request limit so that malicious authenticated users can't take their cognito tokens and make a DoS attack on say a dynamo table.

Otherwise I don't know a way to tie your application auth into AWS auth, so you're left bridging that gap with your own engineering effort.

Comment: I'll consider using API Gateway, although it costs extra money... Thanks!

Comment: If you're writing javascript anyway you might want to look at how the Serverless approach combines lambdas with API gateway.  Pretty sure at the cost of those services you can save quite a bit of money if you can get away from running servers.  Of course that starts to be a lot of stuff to learn and implement at once, but might be worth looking into.

Comment: I used lambda before and found it very useful and cheap, but only when using it for very specific not too demanding purposes. Building a few thousands users app with lambda will cost much more than building your own API. See here: https://www.trek10.com/blog/lambda-cost/ . And also, It's an opportunity to learn a lot about JS and ec2 and other production systems (Like Docker and Kubernetes). Thank you, again!

Comment: That's an awesome link to include for future readers.  I also wanted to point out, that link fails to account for a huge part of real cost, the human involvement in setting up and managing the EC2 instance!  Still, valid point.

Comment: Yeah that's right... But I'm working solo so my time is free (: